# GCP compute instance group autoscaling keeping 2 min instances instead of 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, autoscaling

In GCP, I have created a managed compute instance group  with autoscaling . I have used custom metrics from telegraf for autoscaling the instance group.  I have set min instances to 1 and max instances  to 4.

But, it is creating 2 instance initially and keeps them all the time. When i check metrics the, i could see that metrics has not even touched half the value of threshold.

In details of the instance group, I could that "Target Size" is shown as 2 instead of 1 (Though i haven't mentioned target size in my terraform code since I am using autoscaler).

Terrform Code:-

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "mig-template" {
  name           = "${lower(var.environment)}-${var.service_name}-launch-template${var.name_suffix}"
  machine_type   = var.machine_type 
  can_ip_forward = false
  metadata_startup_script = var.startup_script 
  tags           = ["nomad"]

  disk {
    source_image = data.google_compute_image.debian_buster.id
    auto_delete = true
    disk_size_gb = var.disk_size_gb
    device_name = "xvda"
  }

  network_interface {
    network = data.google_compute_network.my-network.id
    subnetwork  = data.google_compute_subnetwork.my-subnetwork.id
  }

  service_account {

    email  = google_service_account.nomad_service_account.email
    scopes = ["cloud-platform"]
  }

  labels = merge(var.default_tags,
      {
        apica_type   = var.apica_type
        environment = var.environment
        autoscale   = "true"
      }
  )
}

resource "google_monitoring_metric_descriptor" "cpu_metrics" {
  description     = "Allocated CPU for nomad instances"
  display_name    = "nomad_client_allocated_cpu"
  type            = "custom.googleapis.com/${var.telegraf_namespace}/nomad_client/allocated_cpu"
  metric_kind     = "GAUGE"
  value_type      = "DOUBLE"
  unit            = "MHz"
  metadata {
    sample_period = "60s"
    ingest_delay  = "30s"
  }
}

resource "google_monitoring_metric_descriptor" "memory_metrics" {
  description     = "Allocated CPU for nomad instances"
  display_name    = "nomad_client_allocated_memory"
  type            = "custom.googleapis.com/${var.telegraf_namespace}/nomad_client/allocated_memory"
  metric_kind     = "GAUGE"
  value_type      = "DOUBLE"
  unit            = "MBy"
  metadata {
    sample_period = "60s"
    ingest_delay  = "30s"
  }
}

resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "group_manager" {
  name = "${lower(var.environment)}-${var.service_name}-instance-group${var.name_suffix}"

  base_instance_name         = var.instance_base_name
  region                     = var.region
  distribution_policy_zones  = var.distribution-policy-zones 
  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.mig-template.id
  } 

}

resource "google_compute_region_autoscaler" "auto_scaler" {
  depends_on = [google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.group_manager]
  provider = google-beta
  name   = "${lower(var.environment)}-${var.service_name}-autoscaler${var.name_suffix}"
  region   = var.region
  project  = var.project_id
  target = google_compute_region_instance_group_manager.group_manager.id

  autoscaling_policy {
    max_replicas    = 1
    min_replicas    = 4
    cooldown_period = 60
  
  scale_in_control {
    max_scaled_in_replicas {
      fixed = 1
    }
    time_window_sec = 60
  }

  metric {
    name = google_monitoring_metric_descriptor.cpu_metrics.type
    target = "2000"
    type = "GAUGE" 
    filter = "resource.type=\"global\"" 
    }
  metric {
    name = google_monitoring_metric_descriptor.memory_metrics.type
    target = "2000"
    type = "GAUGE" 
    filter = "resource.type=\"global\""
    }
  }
}
```